# How to enable USB passthrough in cuttlefish emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

I know Android QEMU emulator support [USB passthrough](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/start/passthrough) functionality and I have already enabled  this into AAOS(11 & 12 version) emulator.
My question is can we enable similar USB passthrough functionality in cuttlefish emulator AAOS-12.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use crosvm usb `attach`/`detach`/`list` functions

```
./bin/crosvm usb list ./cuttlefish_runtime.1/internal/crosvm_control.sock
```

lsusb
ex:
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

```
./bin/crosvm usb attach 004:001:1d6b:0003 /dev/bus/usb/004/001 ./cuttlefish_runtime.1/internal/crosvm_control.sock
```

```
./bin/crosvm usb detach 1 ./cuttlefish_runtime.1/internal/crosvm_control.sock
```